# Get list of packages with version number, already know how to get list without version number

Tags: bash, debian, apt, package-management

OS : Debian latest.

Hello friends,

I am working on a small tool, where I am required to send the list of manually installed packages installed for a system as a text file. This text file is then pulled up by another agent. Currently, I am able to get the list via below mentioned command, but it does not give me the version number. Any idea how I can get the version number along with it. Thank you.

Command:

```
comm -23 <(apt-mark showmanual | sort -u) <(gzip -dc /var/log/installer/initial-status.gz | sed -n 's/^Package: //p' | sort -u)
```

Kindly let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your exact use-case, `zgrep` may do the trick:

```
zgrep ... /var/log/dpkg.log* | grep installed
```

(Note that the three dots `...` are required)

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the output to `dpkg -s`:

```
comm -23 <(apt-mark showmanual | sort -u) <(gzip -dc /var/log/installer/initial-status.gz  \| 
sed -n 's/^Package: //p' | sort -u) | xargs -n1 dpkg -s |grep 'Package:\|Version:'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked out with the following:

```
dpkg-query -l | awk '{print $2 " Version Number " $3}'
```

Comment: There is a big difference between this command and the given one in your question. Use `diff` to see the difference.